# Mock a closure that manipulates a private field of the unit under test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following code in my unit under test:

```
someDependency.doSomething(element -> {
    privateFieldOfUnitUnderTest += element;
});
```

Some dependency (which I mocked with mockito) calls the method doSomething (in the real code it's doing some async call) with a lambda function callback that modifies a private field of the unit under test.
My question is how to test this properly using mockito (and without using powermocking techniques).

I want the mocked method doSomething to call the callback with some data provided by the unit test.

Comment: I read your question again and I'm confused: is privateFieldOfUnitUnderTest a field of your test case or a private field of someDependency?

Comment: `privateFieldOfUnitUnderTest` is a field of a class which is under testing. Not a field of `someDependency`.

Answer (score 2):

If you mocked `someDependency` all what you can control for `doSomething()` is passing and returned data. The implementation of `doSomething()` is missed. It means the given functional interface will not be triggered inside `doSomething()`. It means even if you can control `element` it will not be involved.

I see the next possible solution:

- Work with spy of `someDependency`
- Call real `doSomething()`
- Have `someDependency.getElement()` which can be mocked in your test
- `doSomething()` should be reworked to work with `getElement()`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Mockito
  .doAnswer(i -> privateFieldOfUnitUnderTest += i.getArgument(0, Integer.class))
  .when(someDependency).doSomething(Matchers.any());
```

I didn't test it, but should work as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Cannot resolve symbol privateFieldOfUnitUnderTest.

Comment: Also this doesn't allow to control what is passed to the callback.

Comment: What you mean what is passed to the callback? The callback itself is defined inside your test (in this case assigning privateField). Isn't it what u want?

Comment: I mean to control "element" which is passed to the callback. The private field is a field of the unit under test which is not accessible from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A UnitTest verivies the *public observable behahior* of the code under test (cut).

If the code snipped in your post is part of that cut then you have to verify that the method `someDependency.doSomething()` is called with the expected parameter:

```
// prepare mocks for dependencies
// prepare cut
// execute tested public method in cut
verify(dependency).doSomething(EXPECTED_SUM_OF_ELEMENT_AND_PRIVATE_PROPERTY_VALUE);
```